# ERROR IN C with STRUCT, POINTER, SCANF_S?

Tags: c, struct, scanf, c-strings

This is my code.... I have some problem with **pointers, scanf_s and struct Persona**.

**ERRORS in line 51, 53, 59 --- > C6011 , C6064, C6067.**

I don't know how to resolve it... I must put Name and Surname into **lista_nomi** and i don't know if the method of putting data that i use, is the right one!

Please HELP ME , i'm a begginer on programming in C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
    Sia dato un insieme di nomi e cognomi di persone. Si scriva un programma in linguaggio
    C che raggruppi le persone con ugual cognome, stampando di seguito tutti i nomi delle
    persone che hanno lo stesso cognome.
    I nomi ed i cognomi devono essere letti da tastiera, come nell’esempio, finché non viene
    letto il nome FINE LISTA. L’ordine con cui si stampano i nomi ed i cognomi non è importante.

*/

#define MAX_PEOPLE 100

struct persona
{
    char* nome[30];
    char* cognome[30];
};

typedef struct persona Persona;

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    do
    {
        printf("Inserisci numero di persone da registrare!\n->");
        scanf_s("%d", &i);
        
        if (i <= 0 || i > MAX_PEOPLE)
        {
            printf("Numero inserito non valido.\nRANGE -> [1 to %d]", MAX_PEOPLE);
        }
    } while (i <= 0 || i > MAX_PEOPLE);
    
    Persona * lista_nomi = (Persona *) malloc(i * sizeof(Persona));

    if (lista_nomi == NULL)
    {
        printf("Errore nell' inizializzazione dell'array lista_nome");
    }

    // Inserimento dei nomi e cognomi

    for (int e = 0; e < i; e++)
    {
        printf("\nInserisci %d persona\n", e + 1);
        printf("\tInserisci Nome -> ");
        scanf_s("%s", &lista_nomi[e].nome);
        printf("\tInserisci Cognome -> ");
        scanf_s("%s", &lista_nomi[e].cognome);

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("Elemento %d -> %s %s", j, lista_nomi[j].nome, lista_nomi[j].cognome);
    }

    free(lista_nomi);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that all C compilers don't use the same error codes, each one's different, so describing the compilation errors as "C6011 , C6064, C6067" is completely meaningless. Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply one more argument that specifies the size pf the character arrays. Also remove the address of operator. For example

```
    printf("\tInserisci Nome -> ");
    scanf_s("%s", lista_nomi[e].nome, ( rsize_t )30 );
    printf("\tInserisci Cognome -> ");
    scanf_s("%s", lista_nomi[e].cognome, ( rsize_t )30);
```

Also you should add the new line character `'\n'` in this call of prontf

```
printf("Elemento %d -> %s %s\n", j, lista_nomi[j].nome, lista_nomi[j].cognome);
```

Pay attention to that your program continue to work even when memory for the array was not allocated.

```
if (lista_nomi == NULL)
{
    printf("Errore nell' inizializzazione dell'array lista_nome");
}
```

that can results in undefined behavior.